# Can I ask LuaTeX to run mktextfm?

Tags: fonts, luatex

From what I [understand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284386/why-does-luatex-not-generate-some-fonts-automatically-in-contrast-with-tex#comment686334_284386), it is a design decision that `luatex` does not run `mktextfm` when needed like `pdftex` does. Is it possible to *ask* luatex to run `mktextfm` when needed?

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\begin{document}
По сути
\end{document}
```

If I run `lualatex` on this, I get the following:

```
! Font \T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
```

The manual solution is to run:

```
mktextfm larm1000
```

But I would rather that be automatic. I suppose I could parse the log to find all the fonts I need to run `mktextfm` on, but that also doesn't feel robust.

A separate workaround is to run `pdftex` before `luatex`, but not all documents that work with `luatex` work with `pdftex` so I would not prefer this workaround.

Comment: I think parsing log is pretty robust though. However there *might* be some Lua callback that is called in precisely this case.

Comment: There's also the option of hooking into the part of LaTeX code that loads fonts and get the font name, but that depends on LaTeX internal code not changing (actually for latex2e it's pretty much a guarantee at this point).

Comment: Why would you want to use legacy 8-bit fonts with LuaTeX in the first place? Surely there are plenty of Cyrillic Unicode fonts around, including Computer Modern.

Comment: @Ingmar good question. I don't, but for some reason some LyX users do. So we run thousands of automated tests to ensure that documents with all kinds of configurations still compile.

Comment: you should really try to disuade thm (and not add any simple interface for using fontnc or luainputnc with luatex (I guess if they insert raw tex code, there is not much you can do)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for this advice. There are definitely some steps LyX can take towards dissuading them.

Comment: having said that I think you could, in principle, use the `find_font_file` callback to configure requests for tfm to trigger maketextfm. In principle....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks!